# Отправляет пустое mail сообщение с вложением

Tags: php, sendmail

Решил прикрутить к своим email сообщениям возможность прикреплять файл. Вроде всё правильно написал, но после отправки сообщения с вложением, обнаруживаю на своей почте совершенно пустое сообщение. Отправляю с локального сервера через SendMail.
Вот код серверной части:

```
$folder = "tmp/";
$attach_file = "test.png";
$boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time()));
// ------------
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
$message_text = "<html><body>HELLO WORLD!</body></html>";
$message = $boundary."\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251'."\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'."\r\n";
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode(iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $message_text)))."\r\n";
// ------------
$open_attach = fopen($folder.$attach_file, "r");
if(!$open_attach) {
    echo "ОШИБКА ОТКРЫТИЯ ФАЙЛА";
} 
$read_attach = fread($open_attach, filesize($folder.$attach_file));
$message .= $boundary."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name = \"".$attach_file."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"."\r\n"; 
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"".$attach_file."\"\r\n";
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode(iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $read_attach)))."\r\n";
$message .= $boundary."--\r\n";
fclose($open_attach);
// ------------
if(!mail("1234@yandex.ru", "Hello World", $message, $headers)) {
    echo "ОШИБКА ОТПРАВКИ СООБЩЕНИЯ";
}
```

Почему приходит пустое сообщение?

Comment: Приведите исходной текст письма.Принт переменной $message

Comment: --3d85f772a6e6b4d13210f0827336aaf6
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ8L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg==

--3d85f772a6e6b4d13210f0827336aaf6
>Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name = "test.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "test.png"


--3d85f772a6e6b4d13210f0827336aaf6--

(Непонятно как пользоваться форматированием текста в комментариях)

Answer (score 1):

У вас не прочитался файл test.png. Попробуйте использовать функцию `file_get_contents()` и проверьте путь.

Кроме того нужно добавить дополнительный \r\n после каждого `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

В `Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=ХХХХХХХХ` нужно приводить boundary без -- (двух дефисов), а во всех остальных случаях - нужно.

Comment: Исправил всё по Вашим рекомендациям, появились некоторые результаты. Теперь на почту приходит и текст и файл. Всё бы ничего, но файл приходит испорченным. Проверил содержимое переменной $message, выяснилось, что файл всё таки прочитался. Незнаю в чём причина. 

Исправил также строку:
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode(iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $read_attach)))."\r\n";
На:
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($read_attach))."\r\n";

Comment: iconv - изменение кодировки. Думаю в Вашем случае оно не нужно. Вопрос решен?

Comment: Никак нет. Я убрал iconv сразу, при исправлении программного кода, после Ваших рекомендаций. Результат: приходит текст и файл. Но файл отображается как испорченный.

Comment: Попробуйте уберите \r\n, который я посоветовал поставить из раздела файла

Answer (score 0):

Полностью рабочий(исправленный) код:

```
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));
$folder = "tmp/";
$attach_file = "test.png";
// -------------------------------
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n\r\n";
$message_text = "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>";
$message = "--".$boundary."\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251' . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode(iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $message_text))) . "\r\n";
// -------------------------------
$read_attach = file_get_contents($folder.$attach_file);
if(!$read_attach) {
    echo "ОШИБКА ЧТЕНИЯ ФАЙЛА";
}
$message .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name = \"".$attach_file."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"."\r\n"; 
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"".$attach_file."\"\r\n\r\n";
$message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($read_attach))."\r\n";
$message .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n";
}
// -------------------------------
if(!mail("your_email@yandex.ru", "HELLO WORLD", $message, $headers)) {
    echo "ОШИБКА ОТПРАВКИ СООБЩЕНИЯ";
}
```

Благодарность пользователю **GrayHoax**